# Setup TFS over internet

Tags: networking, tfs

I have installed TFS on my computer which has a windows7 and is connected to a wireless modem with a static IP address.

I've disabled firewall and allowed 8080 port in both inbound and outbound rules in WF.msc

I can open `computerName:8080/tfs/web` from my pc but but I can't open `http://x.x.x.x:8080/tfs/web`

any idea how do I set this up?

Comment: can you open `computerName:8080` from another computer from another computer on your wireless network?

Comment: I can open 192.168.1.2:8080/tfs/web from another computer (192.168.1.2 is tfs server IP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure your wireless router to forward 8080 TCP port to your `computerName`.

```
Protocol = TCP
Remote host = your external IP
External start port = 8080
External end port = 8080
Internal host = computerName
Internal port = 8080
```

Comment: I'm new to network config, It has only port mapping with these parameters: Protocol, Remote host, External start port, External end port, Internal host, Internal port.

Comment: see edited answer. you could also look for DMZ configuration on the router - that would basically enable your computer to be visible from the internet like the router isn't there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the problem didn't go away.

Comment: could you add a screenshot to your router configuration page?

Comment: I might be missing something, but it does look ok. Maybe the provider is blocking the traffic?

Comment: You may want to remove that image, or at least block out your public IP (assuming it's real) since you are opening ports to your network.

Comment: @Aaron: thanks. I removed it.

Comment: @Knagis: I'll take your advice and check with my ISP.

Comment: I left Remote Host field empty, and set DMZ to my local IP and it worked.